# How to join a domain over VPN?

Tags: vpn, active-directory

I connect to company VPN and I can join the default domain without problems.

In office infrastructure we have a seperate domain which is setup as a test environment.

I can RDC into servers on this test domain, and I can ping the DC of this test domain.

What I would like to do is get my local pc connected to this test domain. I'm connecting over VPN, running Windows 7.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you want to access resources in the test domain or join your laptop to the test domain?

Comment: need to join the off site computer to the domain, because I'm testing AD functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you'll need to join the vpn before logging into the computer. Once on the computer, log into the computer and if dns is properly configured, you'll be able to join the domain and then log in with you domain account to the remote computer.

Here are some details about logging into the vpn before logging into the computer.

http://www.vistax64.com/vista-networking-sharing/71237-how-logon-domain-over-vpn.html

Comment: My problem is I can't join the domain in the local user step. When I try add the computer to the domain, It says can't find the domain.

Comment: When trying to join, are you on the vpn?  If so, are the tcp/ip settings for dns set to use the dns servers within the company network rather than the ISP set settings?

Answer (score 4):

If you have anything like split tunneling in the VPN protocol, it will cause issues in the domain join. You'll need to make sure you are completely on the VPN with no access to your local assets.